# New items on home page PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, e-commerce

I have most recent items displayed on home page and weverythnig was ok till today, I've noticed that the items I've added today didnt appear on my home page and I dont know why here is my code

```
<?php // Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
session_start();

include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 6");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y",     strtotime($row["date_added"]));
    $dynamicList .= ' <div id="test"><div id="wrap" align="center"><div id="columns" class="columns_3"><figure><a class="button" href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img class="img" style="border:#666 0px solid ;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '"   border="1" /></a><div class="new_name">' . $product_name . '<br /></div> <div class="new_price">  £' . $price . '<br /></div><div  class="new_buy"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="style/buy.png" /></a></figure></div></div></div>';
  }  else {
      $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
  }
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: That should work if the new items actually added a correct date that is in the top 6.  Check the data in the db.

Comment: @ AbraCadaver Yes data is correct like I said that was working ok till today

Comment: Well, if the code didn't change, but the data did...?

Comment: @ AbraCadaver thanks I checked again and you right the new elements are not in top 6 of today's items I added like 11 items and only first 6 are displayed but not the latest and I need them to appear, do you know how to fix that, thanks mate

Comment: Change your query from LIMIT 6 to the number that you want to limit to. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the limit to however many you want to display:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15");
```

**Note**: If the only thing being stored is the date with no time then you will need to also order by something else, like id, if you want the actual order they were added:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC, id DESC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: hehehe I was just posting this solution becasue I figured this out after a while but you sir were faster but thank you anyway and good day to you :)